Why the file properties is not opening Windows 11?
When I click on the properties of a file and right-click on it nothing opens. The same when I use the Alt + Enter shortcut.I tried doing various tutorials whether from YouTube or other portals, but nothing helped.

Please take the [tour] and read [ask] - this site is for programming questions.
